# Error on submiting form MVC3 .Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms, properties, razor, model

Hi there I have an error when I submit the following form:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("MainDetails", "ProjectDetails")">Project Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("ProjectAttachments", "ProjectAttachments")">Project Attachments</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Members", "ProjectNetwork", new { IsTab = true })">Project
        Network</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("BulletingBoard", "BulletingBoard")">Bulleting Board</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("BidsReceived", "Bids")">Bids Received</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
  <div id="LowerButton">
    @Html.Hidden("MainStatus", @Model.Status)
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Dashboard", "Dashboard"))
{     
    <button type="button" id="MakeComment">
        Make a Comment
    </button>  
    <input type="submit" id="GoDashBoard" value="Return to Project List" />
}
</div>
```

When I press the button "GoDashBoard", The method "Dashboard" in the controller "Dashboard" is not reached. Instead the following error appears:

[image: error]

It tells me that a model property is beign sent to the server. However, there are no model properties inside the dashboard form.. unless I'm sending many forms at the same time. But I dont think thats possible right? Do you guys have any idea of why is trying to set a model property when I'm not actually sending any?

Update:

this is the  input of the dashboard action:

```
   public ActionResult Dashboard(int page = 1)
    {
        var user = (User)Session["User"];
        if (user != null)
        {...
    }}
```

the input is a default integer. However, I saw the trace of the calls and its submiting another form which is not related to the one im using:
[image]

That form is inside of one of the ajax tabs. I dont understand how one form submits another form and they are not nested. Anyone knows a good workaround? because im thinking of receiving both forms in both  actions and make some validations.

Comment: Can you post the `Dashboard` action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing the form "Dashboard" and instead adding an invisible link. The button would reference the invisible link:

```
@*@using (@Html.BeginForm("Dashboard", "Dashboard"))
     {  *@   
    <button type="button" id="MakeComment">
        Make a Comment
    </button>  
    <button name="button" type="button" onclick="document.location.href=$('#GoDashBoard').attr('href')">Return to Project List</button>
    <a id="GoDashBoard" href="@Url.Action("Dashboard", "Dashboard")" style="display:none;"></a>

    @*<input type="submit" id="GoDashBoard" value="Return to Project List" />*@
@*  }*@
```